# Delta value in render method libgdx

Tags: libgdx, timedelta

I have check delta value in render method in Screen class.. I saw it is not constant. Can any body tell where it come from and what it is? And does it differ in different screen sizes? If it is so how can we overcome this? I am asking this cause my player jump depends upon delta time and sometimes it jumps too high .....

Answer (score 18):

The `deltaTime` has nothing to do with screen sizes. It is the amount of time the *last frame* took to be rendered. Rendered in case of LibGDX also includes all the logic you execute in your `render()` method.

Usually you want a game to run at the same speed on different devices. If your render method looks something like this...

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    float speed = 5f;
    position = position + speed;
}
```

...then the position would change faster on fast devices and less fast on slow devices, just because the render method is called a different amount of times.

To overcome this issue, there is the `deltaTime` which in case of LibGDX is in seconds. To let the position change at the same rate on different devices, you usually do it like this:

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    float speedPerSecond = 5f;
    position = position + (speedPerSecond * deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `float delta` in your `render(delta)` method is the time between the last frame and this frame, given in seconds. You can get this value everywhere, by calling `Gdx.graphics.getDelta()`.
This value is smoothed over n frames.
To get the real time (which is not really neccesary in most cases) you can call `Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime()`.
This value is used to have move the objects in the game, depending on the elapsed time between the frames, instead of moving them at a fixed amount of pixels. To do this you can simply mulitply your `movementSpeed` with this `delta` to get the distance your object should travel.

I would suggest to limit your delta time, as huge delta times (caused by slow devices or something else going on) can mess up for example collision detection. To limit it to, for example, the `delta` time of 30FPS you can simply say `delta = Math.min(delta, 1/30);`

Comment: Ya I am facing a problem that some time My player jump height varies. But how much time should I limit how can I know that?

Comment: Well you have to try, because it depends on the game design. The libgdx `scene2D` `Stage`, for example, limits it to a value of 1/30. So if you play under 30FPS, the delta does not count anymore. Try to use different values and look which is best for you.

Comment: I get different delta vs if I do System.currentTimeMillis myself. What could be the cause of this? If I do System.currentTimeMillis I get consitent low figures, but if I take delta, then occassionally, I get very big figures totally screwing up my tween animation.