# LibGDX Java game shuttering

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a simple infinite runner game. I am using Box2D for physics. When I play the game, I can see the blocks (things you are jumping on) shuttering / moving really fast from side to side (dunno if that's the word I should use). It is like there is something wrong with delta.

My game's logic:

- Array of blocks - static bodies, I have always 10 blocks on the scene (if you can't see it, remove it, spawn new one, etc)
- Player - dynamic body - jumping on the blocks
- Camera - following player

My world has got vertical gravity (makes player fall down). I move the player by updating his linear velocity

```
Vector2 velocity = body.getLinearVelocity();
body.setLinearVelocity(5, velocity.y);
```

Drawing him this way:

```
batch.draw(texture, body.getPosition().x - 0.5f + delta, body.getPosition().y - 0.5f + delta, 1, 1);
```

As you can see, I tried to add delta to the drawing, but that didn't change anything. I draw my blocks the same way.

When I change the physics update time to 60 times per second (same as FPS), game runs much more smoothly, but I can still see that strange effect (my eyes hurt after playing it!).

Do you have any idea what can cause it? If you need anything else, I can add it.

Comment: Is your game running at constant FPS?

Comment: `delta` is not a variable to be used like that, it just tells you the time between loops, if you want a smoothly movement you need to *tween* (or interpolate) your movements or multiply by `delta` the amount of movement you want to add, check the last part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22405543/3998458), maybe could be helpful

Comment: Yeah it's running @60FPS. I tried to change the way I am moving player with delta to: `body.setLinearVelocity(250 * delta, velocity.y);` but its still there :X